# tx:advice element not declared

Tags: transactions, xsd, spring.net

I'm getting the element tx:advice not declared error for my Spring.Net configuration and for the life of me I can't figure out why.  Please help !

My config looks like :

```xml
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.net/tx"
         xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net http://www.springframework.net/schema/objects/spring-objects.xsd
         http://www.springframework.net/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.net/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
         http://www.springframework.net/schema/db
         http://www.springframework.net/schema/db/spring-database.xsd">

<!-- some config settings -->

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="HibernateTransactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="*" isolation="ReadUncommitted" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
</objects>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a declaration for the TxNamespaceParser :

```
<spring>
    <parsers>
      <parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
      <parser type="Spring.Transaction.Config.TxNamespaceParser, Spring.Data" />
      <parser type="Spring.Aop.Config.AopNamespaceParser, Spring.Aop" />
    </parsers>
</spring>
```

doh!

Comment: +1, exactly what I was about to mention; see the [spring docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html#tx-namespace) for an example.

Comment: I found that I still have to register the transaction namespace parser, although [the docs say that since version 1.2.0 you shouldn't have to](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-tx). I never figured out why.

Comment: When you need to do this without an app.config, you can programmatically register parsers, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364782/spring-net-nhibernate-the-http-www-springframework-net-databaseprovider.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marijn.  I'm actually trying to override the default isolation level when using the Transaction attribute declaration on a method see question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7728989/2839 but can't seem to get it working

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframewo...` try installing the xsd schema's in Visual Studio as described [in the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/vsnet.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've followed the advice the, my solution compiles without any warning but on startup of the web app from VS.NET I'm still getting http://www.springframework.net/tx:advice not declared :-(