# How do I override the default isolation level when using the Transaction attribute in Spring.Net

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net, isolation-level, spring-transactions

When using the Transaction() attribute on a method the default isolation level is ReadCommitted.  What I want to do is set the default isolation level to ReadUncommitted in the Spring.NET config ( so as not to modify all the Transaction attribute definitions that exist currently)

How do I do it ? Can it be done with Spring.NET 1.2 ?

I've tried to follow [the documentation](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0-M1/reference/html/transaction.html#tx-txproxyfactoryobject) using tx:advice etc to no avail.

I've even stepped in to the code of Spring with Reflector but all I seem to understand from that, is that Spring simply reads the settings from the Attribute declaration on the method.

Can it be done or am I going to have to go through the code and modify the attribute where necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use e.g.:

```
[Transaction( IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted )]
```

on my repository methods. And it works in conjuction with `<tx:attribute-driven transaction-manager="HibernateTransactionManager"/>`.

```
<object
  name="HibernateTransactionManager"
  type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"
  dependency-check="none">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="MsSqlDbProvider"/>
  <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but I'm actually trying to see if I can avoid actually doing that by setting in the config file a default (for all methods) of isolationLevel.ReadUncommitted while still using  [Transaction()].  I suspect it's not possible though :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create your own transaction interceptor that extends the standard  transaction interceptor. And then hook up that one using ObjectNameAutoProxyCreator instead of the TransactionProxyFactoryObject that you referenced.

Comment: If I find the time I'll try to code this, but that will probably not be any time soon.